# How to dynamically change series colors in HighCharts without using update?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I've got a spline graph with several series and each series has it's own color. There's an option to compare the series with a prime version (so copied, added, and manipulated on a particular variable). That's all fine. However the prime series lines have the same colors as their original counterparts. I can change the color of the originals successfully with the update() function:

```
for (var k = 0; k < x; k++) {
    mychart.series[k].update({color:'#999999'});
}
```

However this has the unfortunate side-effect of removing other options (including animation info, which I need). From [HighCharts docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Series.update):

> Update the series with a new set of options. For a clean and precise handling of new options, all methods and elements from the series are removed, and it is initiated from scratch. Therefore, this method is more performance expensive than some other utility methods like setData or setVisible.

Setting the colour direction and then calling redraw() does nothing:

```
mychart.series[k].color = '#999999';
mychart.series[k].redraw();
```

I've also tried tweaking the colorIndex but to no avail.

Surely there must be a way to modify and redraw the line without throwing away all the options (it works for updating the points just fine).

Comment: I solved this by changing the colors of the original series first, then adding the prime series. Will leave this question unanswered for awhile as it may benefit others. I still don't fully understand why update() drops the animation.

Comment: You should be able to change series color using .attr() method on series graph element: http://jsfiddle.net/coekwv4p/1/ and Point.update() should not affect your animation.